# Алгоритм для нанесения значений данных

Tags: алгоритм

Есть отрезок равный например 400у.е. 
Есть 20 значений, которые надо нанести на этот отрезок и подписать.
Размер одной подписи 5у.е.
Как подписать все 20 значений так, чтобы подписи не наезжали друг на друга? 
Можно иногда поднять на один уровень выше, но не больше.
Кучность подписей может достигать 8 на одно место (или рядом).

Comment: Вообще-то 5*20 = 100, так что все подписи займут только четверть отрезка. В чем проблема?

Comment: Проблем в том, что некоторые надписи могут быть очень близко друг к другу, и если их сразу в одном месте около десятка, значит придется размещать их выше, а не в одном ряду. Не хотелось бы просто их в ряд располагать.

Comment: Я думаю придется сначала расположить в порядке возрастания значений, а потом тупо перебирать новый порядок и заполнять еще массив "занятых мест".